# Laravel 5: 404 Not Found on all routes except home, /index.php extension does not resolve

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404

**Development System:**
Debian "Jessie" Virtual Box, PHP 7.0, PostgreSQL 9.x, Laravel 5.4, testing done on Laravel built-in server

**Production System:**
Ubuntu 16.10 DigitalOcean droplet, PHP 7.0, PostgreSQL 9.x, Laravel 5.4, nginx 1.10.3

Just resolved a 500 error followed by a 502 error with my app which were both permissions problems. Now I can see the main page of my application, but all other routes produce a 404 error. The most common suggestion seems to be that this is an .htaccess error which is diagnosed by attempting to access other routes by prefixing them with index.php/, however this doesn't resolve the issue for me. These routes all function perfectly as is back on the development environment.

Here's my server block:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /home/user/var/www/mydomain.com/public;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your nginx configuration is wrong on the production environment. Can we see your `server` block?

Comment: Added server block above.

Comment: Can you remove `=404` from the end of your query string above?

Comment: Works now. In hindsight that seems very obvious, but I was under the impression given the comments built into the server block that =404 was necessary for a 404-fallback error to be displayed by nginx, especially given examples I'd read tell you to include it. What is the actual function of the =404 syntax, then?

Comment: In the way you utilized it in the query string, it was to always call a 404, if you wanted a fallback then [you'll probably find the answer in this question](http://serverfault.com/a/251699). That's usually what I do.